# linphone-iphone xcode project have rootca.pem error

Tags: ios, xcode, linphone

I have downloaded linphone-iphone xcode project from
"git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-iphone.git"

and properly follow all the instruction in README.md,after i open the project file in xcode i have some error given below.

error: /Users/ballaji/linphone-iphone/liblinphone-sdk/apple-darwin/share/linphone/rootca.pem: No such file or directory

Comment: Check this issue: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-iphone/issues/6

Answer (score 2):

This error caused by missing file "rootca.pem" under the folder "Resources".

1. Cmake generate from linphone zip using file "rootca.cmake"
2. copy from "linphone-sdk" download from it's website
3. copy rootca.pem from latest linphone zip http://www.linphone.org/releases/ios/liblinphone-iphone-sdk-latest.zip